# How can I change colors in an Illustrator file without modifying other aspects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I purchased a stock vector design.

I want to change the preset colors used in vector art and leave everything as it is. The object is made up of bunch of shapes.

As I try to change the colors instead of it looking nice and blended as it did when I have bought it. All I see is the shapes with no gradients or blends.

Since I am new, I do not know the simplest way to change the color "theme" without messing up the way it looks right now.

**Is there an easy way to change colors of an exiting Illustrator file?**

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to edit your question with a sample image so we can properly assist you.  At this time I dont think anyone will be able to help because we cant see what you've done..  and welcome to GD!

Answer (score 2):

Select All and choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork`.

You can then alter colors easily regardless of them being gradients or solid colors.

[image]

[image]

Then just click `OK` when you're done.

This will *not* alter any linked or embedded raster images and may or may not alter raster effects.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Changing gradients]

Hey Jason,

Is this kind of what you're trying to accomplish? If so, my recommendation would be to select the shapes that you want to change the colors on, then go into your gradient panel, shown here on the right (the square icon that has a gradient). Then select the color box on the slide scale>click the menu in the upper right hand corner>RGB>enter hex code into the box in the bottom right.

Boom, gradient color changed, same gradient is still intact.

Hope that helps.

Raelina